# Can not save id in session properly using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, session

I am getting issue. I am trying to save different id at each time click in session but while I am fetching this from session always one id(`i.e-the first saved one.`) is showing. I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
foreach ($catdata as $v) {
?>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="<?php echo $classarr[$counter];?>" onClick="keepSection('<?php echo $v['id']; ?>');"><?php echo $v['name'] ?></a><!-- activemap1 -->
</div>
<?php
$counter++;
if($counter==4){
    $counter=0;
 }
}
```

While click on anchor tag the respective id will save into session by ajax call which is given below.

```
function keepSection(id){
        var url="common.php?action=savecid";
        $.post(url,{"cat_data":id},function(data){  
            var obj=JSON.parse(data);
            console.log('data',obj);
            if(obj.isData==1){
                var v = jQuery("#fyndspaceownsec").validate({
                });
                if (v.form()) {
                    $(".frm").hide("fast");
                    $("#sf2").show("slow");
                }
            }
        })

      }
```

> Common.php:

```
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
$result=array();
if($action=='savecid'){
    $id=$_POST['cat_data'];
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['cid']) && !empty($_SESSION['cid'])){
        unset($_SESSION['cid']);
        $_SESSION['cid']=$id;
        $flag="true";

    }else{
        $_SESSION['cid']=$id;
        $flag="false";
    }
    $result=array("isData"=>1,"cid"=>$_SESSION['cid'],"flag"=>$flag);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Here i am storing the id into session.At each time click i am clearing the session and storing the new id.When i am trying to fetch it its showing only one id which has saved first after each time click.

```
<div class="fyndspacecategory fyndsheightsubc nano">
<div class="nano-content">
  <?php
    echo $_SESSION['cid'];

?>
```

My full code is given below.

```
<div class="fynd-space-itms">
<?php
$classarr = array("item-exhibitation maploc", "item-parking maploc", "item-offices maploc", "item-storage maploc");
$sql="select * from category order by id desc";
                                                        $catdata=$dbobj->db_get_data($sql);
$counter=0;
foreach ($catdata as $v) {
?>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="<?php echo $classarr[$counter];?>" onClick="keepSection('<?php echo $v['id']; ?>');"><?php echo $v['name'] ?></a><!-- activemap1 -->
</div>
<?php
    $counter++;
if($counter==4){
    $counter=0;
}
}
<button class="btn nextbtnbgdiv open2" type="button">Next <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
<div class="fyndspacecategory fyndsheightsubc nano">
    <div class="nano-content">
      <?php
        echo $_SESSION['cid'];

    ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Here when user will click on `next` button the second part div section will display and fetch the id from session.

Suppose first time clicked `id=16` stored into the session and the `echo` will print the value `16` and in second time click `id=17` stored onto session but this time also the `echo` value is coming `16` which is my problem. I need at each time click the old id will remove and new id will store and when the `echo` should print new value after each time click.Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768816/php-session-variables-not-preserved-with-ajax

Answer (score 0):

You would use isset and empty:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['blah']) && !empty($_SESSION['blah'])) {
   echo 'Set and not empty, and no undefined index error!');
}
```

array_key_exists is a nice alternative to using isset to check for keys:

```
session_start();
if(array_key_exists('blah',$_SESSION) && !empty($_SESSION['blah'])) {
    echo 'Set and not empty, and no undefined index error!');
}
else 
{
 echo "session is not set";
 }
```

Make sure you're calling session_start before reading from or writing to the session array.

Comment: Let me to check and let you know.

Comment: same issue sir.Its not clearing the previous id (`unset($_SESSION['cid']);`).

Comment: you have to check whether its come in if condition or not

I update the answer to check that

Comment: yes,each time its entering into if statement.` `$result=array("isData"=>1,"cid"=>$_SESSION['cid'],"flag"=>$flag);` also returns the perfect values but its not present in session while fetching.

Comment: what you get for that session value ?

have you print

Comment: each time i am getting `Array ( [cid] => 16 )` while printing the session.BUt each time i am passing the cid value different.

Comment: Here i can say that all html part are in same page means user is passing and fetching the id from the same page.

Comment: I have posted the full html code .Please check this.

Comment: Can u please attach screenshot of your output